# How to properly type a generator function in Hack

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I'm playing around with Hack for a bit and tried to create a generator function using the `yield` keyword. The [documentation](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.annotations.generators.php) states that the return type of such a function should be the `Continuation` interface. However, when running `hh_client` on the source code example of the generator function I get the following output:

> ./test.php:4:3,7: Invalid yield (Typing[4110])
>   ./test.php:3:17,28: This is an object of type Continuation
>   ./test.php:4:3,7: It is incompatible with an object of type Generator (result of function with 'yield' in the body)

This is test.php:

```
<?hh

function gen(): Generator<int> {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

function foo(): void {
  foreach (gen() as $x) {
    echo $x, "\n";
  }
}

foo();
```

Changing the result type to `Generator` gives even more warnings. What is the correct way of typing a generator function?

Comment: Have you tried it without a result type? Like in the docs http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: Yes, that works but kind-of defeats the purpose. In order to be able to defined the script as _strict_ hack, a return type must be defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any mention of `Continuation` in the docs is outdated and wrong. There's [an open issue about it](https://github.com/hhvm/hack-hhvm-docs/issues/536).

The correct type is `Generator<Tk, Tv, Ts>` -- there are actually three type parameters there. Here's an example of what they mean:

```
$r = yield $k => $v;
```

The type of that generator is `Generator<Tk, Tv, Ts>`, where `Tk` is the type of `$k`, `Tv` is the type of `$v`, and `Ts` is the type of `$r`.

For your code, this should work:

```
function gen(): Generator<int, int, void> {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
```

The first `int` because there is implicitly an integer key; the second `int` because you are `yield`ing `int`s, and the `void` since you don't care what values are sent into the generator.